Subdivision Surface Node in Geometry Nodes Creating Unexpected Creases After Merge by Distance
I'm experiencing an unexpected behavior with the Subdivision Surface node in Blender's Geometry Nodes. Here's my workflow:
Started with a mesh
Extruded the mesh
Joined it with the previous mesh to create bottom faces
Used a Merge by Distance node
The issue: After applying the Subdivision Surface node, it's behaving as if there's a crease attribute on the vertices that were merged by the Merge by Distance node. This results in sharp edges or unexpected creasing where the geometry was joined.

I'm looking for insights on why this might be happening and potential solutions to achieve smooth subdivision without these artificial creases. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know of any workarounds within the Geometry Nodes setup?

Wrong face normals

The problem is the normals of the faces are pointing upwards and they get extruded upwards (or generally in the direction in which the normals are pointing).
The original faces are also pointing upwards - even after joining the geometry and merging the vertices. But this means now, the bottom face normals are pointing in the wrong direction inside the closed meshes.
These flipped faces build a natural boundary to the other correctly oriented faces, which works like a crease. To change this, you have to flip the original faces with a Flip Faces node before the Join Geometry.
Here in this example I have the Face Orientation overlays enabled and rotated one of the planes so that you can see the original face at the bottom - it shows red, so the inside is pointing outwards and the connecting edges are creased:

But if you place a Flip Faces node between the original faces and the Join Geometry node, everything turns blue and the creased edges are gone:

